# Calculate sum based on field inputs

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-calculation

How can I sum the values of multiple text inputs?

Currently the sum is not correct as it keeps on remembering and summing previous values that were in the input fields before.

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <legend>Risicopotentieel</legend>
  <label for="email">Email address:</label>
  <select class="selectpicker" id="selectpicker1">
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
    <option value="4">text4</option>
  </select>
  <label for="email">Email address:</label>
  <select class="selectpicker" id="selectpicker2">
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
    <option value="4">text4</option>
  </select>
  <label for="email">Email address:</label>
  <select class="selectpicker" id="selectpicker3">
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
    <option value="4">text4</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <legend>Score</legend>
  <label for="email">&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="scorefield1">
  <label for="email">&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="scorefield2">
  <label for="email">&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="scorefield3">
  <label for="email">Totaalscore</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="riskpottotalscore" id="riskpottotalscore">
</div>
```

The jQuery code first copies the value of the selected option to an input field. This works fine. Thereafter, I want to calculate the sum and that is were it goes wrong. The variable *totalPoints* keeps remembering its scores, but I only want to calculate the sum over the values that are actually selected in score field 1, 2 and 3:

```
scorefieldrisk: function(){
    totalPoints = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            $('select[id$="selectpicker' + i + '"]').on("change", function() {
                document.getElementById('scorefield'+i).value = this.value;
                if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                    totalPoints +=(parseInt(this.value));
                    document.getElementById('riskpottotalscore').value = totalPoints;
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redo the sum from zero each time.

Your code could be simplified to have just one function as handler for all `select` elements. Also you can use the unitary `+` operator to convert the string value to number:

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
    totalPoints = 0;
    $('.selectpicker').each(function() {
        totalPoints += +this.value;
    });
    $('#riskpottotalscore').val(totalPoints);
});
```